# JSoup: How to parse the cells of 1st column of a table?

Tags: java, jsoup

```
<tr>
 <td rowspan="2" valign="top">abc</td>
 <td rowspan="2" valign="top">2013-06-20</td>
 <td>Hardware</td>
 <td>x86_64</td>
 <td>All</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>OS</td>
 <td>Linux</td>
 <td>All</td>
</tr>

Elements NTs = doc.select("table td:eq(0)");
  for (Element NT : NTS) {
       System.out.println(NT.text());
}
```

Current Output:

```
abc
OS
```

Required Output: `abc`

plz help me ..

Thank you

Comment: what is this, something like JSoup ?

Comment: Ok, I added the jsoup tag for you.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense - you said you want to parse the 1st column of the table, well 'OS' is the first column of a new row (note the <tr> tag just before it)

Comment: Do you want to parse the first column of the first ROW of your table? If so, does something like `table tr:eq(0), td:eq(0)` work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the element in the first column, first row you can just use a simple regular expression:

```
    String t = input;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[<tr><td[.]*>]{1}(\\p{Alnum}*)</td>");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(t);
    String ris = "";
    if (m.find())
        ris = m.group(1);
```

Comment: First row first column

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. If you find you need to change something in an answer you've given, there is no need to comment on your own answer, you can just edit (click the `edit` link below the answer) and make improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're using Jsoup there's no need to use regex as suggested in the other answer. First you get the rows of your table, and then for each row get the first column, and then get the text. Here's a simple example assuming you have one table with the data from your example.

```
Elements rows = doc.select("tr");
for (Element row : rows) {
   // Get the first column for the row
   Element col = row.select("td").get(0);

   // Get the text for the element
   String text = col.text();
   System.out.println(text);
}
```

Example

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" valign="top">abc</td>
    <td rowspan="2" valign="top">2013-06-20 </td>
    <td>Hardware</td>
    <td>x86_64</td>
    <td>All</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>OS</td>
    <td>Linux</td>
    <td>All</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I don't know why you expect to only get `abc`